# Display comments on adaptive cards in BOT emulator

Tags: bots, adaptive-cards

I am displaying some data in using adaptive card in BOT emulator,I want to add one comment section there.I tried this way:

```
{
                                "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                                "title": "Comment",
                                "card": {
                                    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                                    "body": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "Input.Text",
                                            "id": "test",
                                            "isMultiline": true,
                                            "placeholder": "Enter your comment",

                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "actions": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "Action.Submit",
                                            "id":"submit",
                                            "title": "OK",

                                            "data":
                                            {
                                                "test":""
                                            }

                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
                                }
                            }

                        ]
```

but not getting any output when click on OK action.How can we do it?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: What output are you expecting when you type something in the comment section and click on OK ? Can you add a screenshot of the card displayed on the emulator?